# Get option value from select menu with variable

Tags: php, html

There is the code in index.php:

```
<select name="select" id="select_invoice">
    <option value="">--- Please select ---</option>
    <?php echo $obj->printOption(); ?>
</select>
```

The class is follow:

```
class SelectOption {
    private $query_names;
    private $selected_index = '';

    public function SelectOption($query_names=''){
        if($query_names) $this->query_names = $query_names;
        if($query_names) $this->query_names = $query_names;
    }

    public function printOption(){
        echo $this->getOption();
    }

    public function get_diretory($query_names) {
        print '<select name="files">';
        $directory = dir($query_names) or die($php_errormsg);
        print '<option> --Please select-- </option>';
        while (false !== ($f = $directory->read())) {
            if (is_file($directory->path.'/'.$f)) {
                print '<option> ' . $f . '</option>';
            }
        }
        $directory->close();
    }
} 

$query_names = 'file_directory';
$obj = new SelectOption($query_names);
$obj->get_diretory($query_names);
```

How can I get the option value from this select menu and find the file in the directory and read it?

Comment: Post the form and inspect the $_POST variable. Then try to write a script to find the file. If you fail, ask again.

Comment: question is way too broad, start at the beginning, and ask a specific question when you are stuck.

Comment: I am stuck here:

<select name="select" id="select_invoice">
 <option value="<? echo $obj->printOption(); ?>">--- Please select ---</option>
 <?php echo $obj->printOption(); ?>
</select>

It gives me the select menu with the names inside my directory.

I need to write the function which will get the option value and open this file.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getOption()` in your class, but there isn't such a function in your class definition.

```
public function printOption(){
    echo $this->getOption(); // where is this function in your class??
}
```

Since you're actually making use of the `printOption()` in your html page, which is using `getOption()`, you're not getting anything out of it. In fact, it should be throwing an error.

Comment: I did not write it, but there is my function:

public function getOption(){
$s = '';
$selected = '';
foreach($this->query_names as $key => $val){
if(! empty($this->selected_index)){
if($this->selected_index == $key) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
else $selected = '';
}
$s .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$selected.'>'.$val.'</option>';
}
return $s;
 
}